# a problem of my bitcoin-core

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

My BTC wallet was `bitcoin core ver. 0.12.1`

After sending my BTC to another address, and waiting for two days status was 0 confirmation, maybe be because the transaction fee was not enough,

So I found a solution from google, `-salvagewallet`, then it seemed to work

But today I try to send my BTC again, after I insert my pass-phrase, a window show up which says

`assertion failed program:C:\........bitcore-qt.exe file:wallet/crypter.cpp,line 190 expression: false`

if click ignore button, it says pass-phrase incorrect.

if click retry,  it says runtime error.

don't know how to solve this problem

[image: mingw runtime assertion]

Comment: Where you able to recover the keys after giving `-salvagewallet` comment and did that transaction got confirmed ?

Comment: @jgm 
sorry ,i did not understand your reply. i did not know much of the `-salvagewallet` command. i use it just to cancel a transaction.

Comment: @jgm by checking the blockchain.info, that transaction was not confirmed, furthermore, no record of that anymore.

Comment: "Assertion failed" indicates that you have encountered a bug in Bitcoin Core.  You can report it at https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/contribute/issues

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload your bitcoin node by reinstalling, backup your wallet.dat to be sure you got that safe!

You can just uninstall the wallet without emptieng your data folder first, safes you some downloading. After that delete all files in the data directory except: blocks folder and wallet.dat.

Install bitcoin qt again and make sure you pick the right data directory again. Opening of the wallet will take a while due to checking of the blockchain and building the chainstate.

Probably your error is nog gone.